# Exclude certain code from being auto formatted in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, autoformatting

WebStorm auto-formats my js file perfectly.

However, there is a situation I want to exclude some code from being auto-formatted, like anything between `<pre><code>` and `</code></pre>`. Auto-format introduces new white spaces. Normally it's not a problem. However, I want to preserve the white spaces between my `<pre><code>` and `</code></pre>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style`
2. `HTML | Other`
3. Make sure that such tags are listed in `Keep white spaces inside` list